# Bulk Insert return error Msg 7399 and Msg 7330

Tags: sql-server, bulkinsert

My problem  is when I run the bulk insert it return the following error. Any idea on the error? Some help is appreciated.

Actually regarding this issues my testing environment able to execute normally but my production server return this error.

Error message:

> Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> The OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
>
> Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
> Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".

Code:

```
 BULK INSERT Table_ZZ 
 FROM 'e:\Folder\sometextfile.txt'
 WITH 
     (ROWTERMINATOR = '')
```

Comment: Update SQL parches solve this issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating SQL Patches solve my problem.
Before the SQL server are not yet being patches, one day decide to do patches, and suddenly solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the CSV fields are correct, the error could be due to number of columns in the DB not matching the CSV pattern (newly created columns or whatever).

In addition to this, i suggest you to consider the newline character as the row terminator, using its ASCII code:

```
(ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0A')
```

Hope this helps.